# Probability of 2 different suits

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say you draw 4 cards from a standard 52 card deck. What is the probability you have exactly 2 different suits?

> Lets first select the suits. $4\choose2$. There remain $26$ cards from which we select $4$. But we subtract the instances all cards are the same suit which occurs in $2\cdot{13\choose4}$ instances.
> Result: $\frac{{4\choose2}\left({{26\choose4} - 2\cdot{13\choose4}}\right)}{52\choose4}$ Is this correct? If so is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Looks good to me. You could also count $4\times\binom{13}{3}\times 39+\binom{4}{2}\times\binom{13}{2}^2$ for the numerator.

Comment: I see no way to provide a more elegant solution :-).

Answer (score 1):

Your way is correct. A different solution isto split it up into cases. There are two ways for us to have *exactly* 2 suits: two and two (SSHH) or three and one (SSSH). We want to choose 2 cards from each suit for the first option, $13 \choose 2$, and we do this twice, which is ${13 \choose 2 }^2$. For the second option, we have $13 \choose 3$ and $13 \choose 1$, and we can do this two ways (SSSH and HHHS) for each two suits we choose. But, we also have $4 \choose 2$ options for suits, so our total number is $${4 \choose 2} ({13 \choose 2}^2 + 2 {13 \choose 3}{13 \choose 1})$$ Which according to mathematica, unless I typed something in wrong, is 81,120, the same as yours. And  of course there are $52 \choose 4$ total, so our probability would be $$\frac{{4 \choose 2} ({13 \choose 2}^2 + 2 {13 \choose 3}{13 \choose 1})}{52 \choose 4} = \frac{1248}{4165} = 0.29964 $$ This solution is not inherently more elegant than yours, but it is possibly easier to understand, depending on the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is valid, and reasonably elegant.

In fact, for problems of this type, the *complementary approach*, which is what your approach amounts to, is often the easiest.

In this particular problem, the direct approach is also
routine enough.

The denominator stays at $~\displaystyle \binom{52}{4},~$ and the numerator goes to

$$\left[ ~4 \times 3 \times \binom{13}{3} \times \binom{13}{1} ~\right] + \left[ ~\binom{4}{2} \times \binom{13}{2} \times \binom{13}{2} ~\right]. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, for the first term, you have to pick the suit which will contribute three cards, and then pick the suit which will contribute one card.

In (1) above, for the second term, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}~$ ways of deciding which two suits will contribute two cards each.